# Is it possible to recover Oracle data from a broken installation that does not permit expdp?

Tags: database, oracle, recovery

I have an Oracle instance on hand in which all of the Windows services have mysteriously disappeared. Naturally this means that I have no TNS listener running and cannot create a backup with the usual expdp command.

As far as I can tell, all of the application files including datafiles are still intact. I have no idea what else might have been damaged by whatever removed the services, so my thinking is that I'd like to somehow create a .dmp file from the datafiles, or install a new instance of Oracle and somehow import/tie in those files. Any time I've ever touched datafiles in the past everything breaks so I'm trying to be careful about my approach.

Has anyone experienced something like this, and if so how were you able to recover data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to 'export' if the database is not open.

Have you been taking any rman backups?  If not, why not?

The VERY FIRST thing you should do is COPY all of the data, redo, init, spfiles, any rman backup files and archivelog files to a safe location so that you do not break things like you say you have done in the past.

The second thing I'd be doing is figure out how a bunch of Windows services 'mysteriously dissappeared'.  That is very troubling.

The next thing I'd do is determine if the ORACLE_HOME, and the oracle entries in the registry are intact.

You can recreate the listener service by simply going to command prompt (as administrator), setting ORACLE_HOME and PATH correctly, and issuing a 'lsnrctl start'.

If you are very lucky, you could use '[oradim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntqrf/about-administering-an-oracle-database-instance-using-oradim.html#GUID-BFE19571-26EE-41D2-B7E6-03C98C7C4452)' to recreate your database services and from there start your databases.

Comment: I'm supporting someone else who clearly did not have a sufficient backup solution in place. I'm finding that some things like spfiles are missing, and from what I can tell the only potentially helpful contents of their Oracle install folder left are DBF files, CONTROL01 and 02 CTL files, redo logs, and some init ora files. Thanks for your feedback; I've already taken a copy of the remaining oracle folder and will give that listener service fix a try.

Comment: The ORACLE_HOME variable is gone as are all *.ora files, but oradim allowed me to create an oracle service. If I can get the TNS listener back up and running long enough to pull a .dmp file, I can just reinstall from scratch and use that backup to restore everything they need.

Comment: The listener has nothing to do with it.  If you were able to create a service with oradim, your next step would be to see if you can open the database, using sqlplus at a command prompt. You have a very complex problem here and it strikes me that it is beyond the intent, scope, and format of SO.  I think you'd be better served by discussing it on Oracle's Groundbreakers forum ... https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/3063-general_questions1